# How to move files on a filesystem remotely without downloading and then uploading the content on the client?

Tags: ssh, filesystems, ftp, network-shares, remote-access

I have a home server box set up running Windows 7 that is usually managed remotely (either from the local network or an external network) and there are often times that there is a requirement to be able to move large files (5-30+ GB) from one folder to another on the box.

How can I allow for the files to be moved between folders on the machines local filesystem without needing to waste unnecessary network bandwidth (for instance: using smb/nfs shares on a local network downloads the files to the client first, before uploading them back to the new folder on the server). This kind of behaviour especially annoying when the client connecting is wireless, or the client is on an external network (my upload speed is 2.4mbps), so it's very slow. Another limitation I have with this is obviously the fact that network shares cannot easily be mounted from an external location (unless using sshfs, which seems fairly limited in this regard).

I run an Arch Linux VM on the machine which has these fileshares mounted, and I manage that VM via SSH mostly. I assume I can achieve the above via SSH without any issues, but my concern here is that I want others who have access to the box to be able to move and copy files on the box easily (on Windows, and with a GUI), both when connected to the local network and externally.

RDP/RDC or any sort of VNC/TeamViewer setup to allow GUI access to the box is not ideal and I would like to avoid it if possible, as the users are not very computer literate.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how this can be achieved?

So far I've determined:
SSHFS is no good.
FTP is no good.
SMB/CIF/NFS is no good, and also can't be accessed externally.
SSH should work (I imagine), but is too complicated for computer illiterate users
RDC/RDP would work in theory, but it's a very verbose and ugly solution, that gives the users more access and control to the system than I would like.

Comment: What do you mean, RDP would give the users more access than you would like? Create a new user account and assign it restricted permissions and then let them RDP with that login??

Comment: @rism It would give them the ability to power the system down, browse the web, run random files, etc. Another reason for not wanting to use RDP is also due to convenience. The server also doubles as a HT PC (always-on plex home theatre box) and RDPing into the box causes another issue there, as it would interrupt people watching.